# How do I add line breaks to my tweets on Twitter.com?

Tags: twitter

How can I add line breaks to a tweet using Twitter.com? I have tried pressing enter, but that sends the tweet.

Comment: Posted this Q&A because my web search found a bunch of articles that were like "OMG Twitter started supporting line breaks! What can you use them for? Were they right or wrong? Can you do it via the API?!" but no "here's what to press."

Comment: You can also just create a line break in your text editor of your choice and copy and paste it into Twitter.com or your standard Twitter client.

Answer (score 5):

## Shift + Enter

At least on OSX in Chrome, Shift + Enter adds a line break.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: In edit box press (do not release ALT button while you are pressing numbers)

```
ALT + (in numpad) 255
```

after you release ALT button, it will create a white space. Copy that and use as much you need.

resource is:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx_4PlIo5pc